# "You must install .NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.4 (x64)" error

Tags: windows-10, installation, .net-core

I have created a simple Hello World application using Visual Studio 2022. The application is a WPF application that targets the .NET 6.0 framework. There is no code, just a "Hello World" TextBlock in `MainWindow.xaml`. When I try running the binaries on a Windows 10 machine, I get the following message box:

> To run this application, you must install .NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.4
> (x64). Would you like to download it now?

[image: you must install .NET Desktop Runtime]

When I run the `dotnet --info` command, it displays the following:

> Host (useful for support):   Version: 6.0.4   Commit:  be98e88c76
>
> .NET SDKs installed:   No SDKs were found.
>
> .NET runtimes installed:   Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
>
> To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

At this point I feel like I have everything I need but I can't get the application to run.

I have downloaded .NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.4 from [this download page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0). It installed without any issues.

This happens on multiple machines I have tested with, including:

1. Windows 10 "MSIX Packaging Tool Environment" image in Hyper-V
2. Windows 11 "dev environment" image in Hyper-V
3. Two Windows 10 development machines.

### Recreating the issue

1. Using Visual Studio, create a new WPF Application targeting .NET 6.0.
2. Build the application.
3. Copy EXE and DLL from `bin/Debug/net6.0-windows` to another machine.
4. Run EXE on the other machine.

Comment: Have you installed .NET 6.0.4 on the other machine?

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the installed versions of .NET from Add/Remove Programs.  You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment . Do you have the 64-bit .NET 6.0.4 Desktop Runtime installed or the 32-bit 6.0.4 Desktop Runtime installed?  Due to the type of application if you have only the .NET Runtime 6.0.4 installed that is the incorrect download.

Comment: @Mokubai yes .NET 6.0.4 is installed, the `dotnet --info` output is from the other machine (the machine the application is being run on). The development machine also has .NET 6.0.4.

Comment: I just does not see it and is not supposed to. Only some executables see the Runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of copying the executable out of the debug folder, use the Publish feature and select the "self contained" option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, that is a better approach and what I have ended up doing.

Comment: No, because the self-contained option causes a publish error.

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque what error? You should troubleshoot that first.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville unfortunately that's not possible, because my project type doesn't allow the "self-contained" option as I understand it, hence the error.

Comment: this should work but I am now in a situation where even though I am publishing self-contained, I am still getting the "you must install" prompt

Answer (score 6):

The Build process generates:

1. `assembly_name.deps`
2. `assembly_name.pdb`
3. `assembly_name.runtimeconfig.json`

I was able to launch the application by including the `runtimeconfig.json` file.

With .NET Framework applications, it was possible to simply copy the EXE and DLLs but it seems like this is not possible with .NET Core applications.

The better approach for my needs is to use Publish to generate a [single-file EXE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli) that contains everything the application needs. The file it generates is pretty big though, about twice the size as my previous releases.

Comment: Whether it's better to create a (comparatively humongous) self-contained application should be carefully evaluated (mostly whether you control the target environment or not). IIRC the official documentation has some good points. Just for your and others' information.

Comment: @DanielB good point, compared to the .NET Framework releases I was able to do just by sending out EXEs and DLLs, this humongous. Even a Framework-dependent Single-file EXE is double the size of my .NET Framework releases.

Comment: "With .NET Framework applications, it was possible to simply copy the EXE and DLLs but it seems like this is not possible with .NET Core applications." - It actually is possible.  I have done it before.  The contents of `runetimeconfig.json` would explain the reason it was required.

Comment: @Ramhound in my HelloWorld test, the `runtimeconfig.json` file contains: `  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "frameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      }
    ]
  }`. There's nothing special here?

Comment: My folder already contains these files but still doesn't work. This is not the answer.